# How to draw border differently for each row in a Grid of wxPython?

Tags: wxpython

I would like to draw border for each row in a wxPython grid different (e.g. bold or broken line) based on data in the respective row. How can I achieve this result?

I am using python 2.6 and what I need is some pointers and/or suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the wxPython demo. I think the demos that you'll find the most helpful are the following:

- wx.Grid showing Editors and Renderers
- GridLabelRenderer which is from wx.lib.mixins.gridlabelrenderer

Those will probably get you started. When you get stuck, ask on the wxPython mailing list. They'll be able to help you out.